# Long labels in list overlap when using ragged2e

Tags: enumitem, ragged2e

I defined a new list using the `enumitem` package. The content of the list varies in many ways. Sometimes a label has two or three lines and the item has only one line. I can prevent overlap of the labels with adding a line break to the one line item - all good until here.

Now, I have to use the `ragged2e` package because I need left aligned text throughout the entire, long document. As soon as I activate `ragged2e`, the line break does not seem to have any effect and the long label overlaps with the following label.

I tried to solve the issue by defining the label alignment (from [Description list with right alignment of labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33334/description-list-with-right-alignment-of-labels) and [multi-line label in enumitem: make list content vertically align with the first line of label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580504/215495) among other posts). But this does not help. What can I do to make `ragged2e` work with this list?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetLabelAlign{mylistalign}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\raggedright#1}}} 
\newlist{mylist}{description}{2} 
\setlist[mylist]{style=multiline,leftmargin=4cm,align=mylistalign}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
    \item [Regular label] with one line content
    \item [Regular label] \lipsum[1]
    \item [Extra long extra long extra long extra long label] but has only one line content. \\
    \item [Extra long extra long extra long label] \lipsum[2]
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use ``\\`` to create space, use e.g. `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I took the  ```\\```   from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207379/how-to-typeset-list-labels-with-multiple-lines and then suspected `ragged2e` to be the culprit because this solution worked without it.